# Apt-get update hit for Remmina after applying apt-get purge

Tags: 18.04, updates, ppa, launchpad, remmina

Before, I had remmina installed for remote dekstop work. To uninstall that software, I have used `apt-get purge remmina`, but when looking at the output of `apt-get update` one of the hits  is still:

```
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/remmina-ppa-team/remmina-next/ubuntu bionic InRelease
```

What causes this to show up and how should it be removed?

Comment: The PPA is not the software. It is the source out on the internet where you get the software from. Open your Software & Updates control panel and delete the source there. FYI: Remmina is in the Ubuntu repositories; you didn't need to add the PPA in the first place.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:<for remina>`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!